# Downloading and Installing Ruby from the command line

Tags: ruby, installation

I would like to install ruby from the command line. I don't mind where it gets installed from but I guess [Here](http://rubyinstaller.org/) would probably be the best place.

The aim is to use ocra to provide a one click installer that runs a ruby script through the command line. Using the backsticks `` arguments method in ruby to install a list of gems along with it. This way, should I decide to change computer, I can run the ruby install as a .exe file and it will do it all for me.

Will this method work? What do you think? What would the command be to actually download and run the rubyinstaller" from the command line?

I am running windows XP.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a Windows/DOS solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automatically pulling down from the web, you can try [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Then you can point it at the [installer url](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75127/rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p290.exe).

**Edit**: (thanks to excellent suggestion by  Ninjaxor)

You can then invoke installer via either the [/silent or /verysilent command line options](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#wiki-silent_install).

Comment: Ruby Installer has command line switches you can use to automate the install.  Using AutoIT is obviously much sloppier and can lead to problems.    https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#wiki-silent_install